# CRM 2015 Associate Custom Entity With Multiple Other Entites

Tags: entity, dynamics-crm-2015

I have implemented a text messaging integration into our CRM2015 using a custom entity to hold the sent and received text messages.

I am trying to find a way to associate a text message to one of multiple other entities in a sane way. For instance a text message might relate to a case, opportunity, order etc. How can I store the relationship?

I know an activity entity can do this but that gives us some restrictions such as not making it easy to see the SMS in a view.

Any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 0):

You could create your custom Text Message entity as an [activity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309626.aspx) (which you mention yourself). This is the solution I would recommend. Standard activity entities are e.g. Email, Phone Call, Fax, and Letter. Your custom Text Message entity would fit right in.

I disagree with your statement that:

> I know an activity entity can do this but that gives us some
>   restrictions such as not making it easy to see the SMS in a view.

A view of all activity entities can be created, just like all your custom Text Message entities could be shown in a view.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamics CRM has the concept of [connections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328381.aspx), which represent an any-to-any relationship (between connection enabled entities). You could thus enable your Text Message entity for connections and be able to connect it to any other connection enabled entity in the system.

This solution can be used in case you do not want to create your Text Message as an activity entity.